# same button in multiple activities

Tags: android, android-layout, button, android-activity, widget

I want a **button/widget**(don't know the name) that doesn't change between activities/layouts. Putting functionality of button aside, how can i have button/widget like "du recorder" app that stays on top of all activities:

[image: DU Recorder]

[image: DU Recorder]

Answer (score 0):

As per my there is nothing like button/widget what you want but you can implement that if you are ready to write some code.
You can have a look at the following projects

https://github.com/JustinScott/AppFloater

https://github.com/vickychijwani/BubbleNote

https://github.com/sezeryesiltas/chat-head-demo

https://github.com/callmekarthik/FBChatHeadExample

https://github.com/BrotherV/Floating-ArcMenu